# fastlane - A Distribution Provisioning profile should be used when submitting apps to the App Store

Tags: ios, testflight, fastlane, fastlane-deliver

I want to distribute a **development** build via testflight

Here is my `fastfile`

`desc "Push a new debug beta build to TestFlight"
  lane :debug_beta do
    build_app(workspace: "MyApp.xcworkspace", 
      scheme: "MyApp", configuration: "Debug",
      export_method: "development"
    )
    upload_to_testflight
  end`

Here is the error I am getting:

> [Transporter Error Output]: ERROR ITMS-90161: "Invalid Provisioning Profile. The provisioning profile included in the bundle com.MyApp [Payload/MyApp.app] is invalid. [Missing code-signing certificate]. A Distribution Provisioning profile should be used when submitting apps to the App Store. For more information, visit the iOS Developer Portal."
>   [17:41:14]: Transporter transfer failed.

Is development build no more supported on testflight?

Comment: You can't push debug builds to TestFlight, you push release builds. I guess you could create a new scheme that had the provisioning profile settings of release with the compilation options of debug, but you can't use the standard debug scheme.

Comment: is `export_method: "development"` no more valid?

Comment: You can export a development build for advocacy deployment, but it isn't valid for TestFlight. You need an AppStore build for TestFlight.